# Read multiple lines in a single excel cell using python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Is there a way to read multiple lines in a single excel cell, line by line. I need this for accessing the signal names and its values

Let say the below three lines are in one excel cell

Signal1: 20

signal2: 30

signal3: 40

I want to access these, line by line separately to fetch the signal name and its value using python win32com. I can do it by if these lines are in individual cells but, I cant go with this method, as there is some dependency.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: grab the cell's contents, which'll just be a string. then use normal string operations to break that string into multiple separate ones.

Comment: What method? What dependency? Any error message? Any code to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell will be returned as a single string with `\n` characters for each line. As such, a standard Python `split` can be used to give you a list of lines:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r"E:\Python temp\example.xls")
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 1")
print ws.Range("A1").Value.split('\n')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Giving something like:

```
[u'Signal1: 20', u'signal2: 30', u'signal3: 40']
```

Answer (score 1):

## importing csv module

import csv

filename = "test.csv"

output = []

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:

## creating a csv reader object

```
csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

## extracting each data row one by one split by new line

```
for row in csvreader:
    output.append(row[0].split('\n'))
```